# getting disallowed error for top command

Tags: scripts, top

while entering top command from a script getting the below error:

```
praveen.kumar@MUM:/home/admin$ top -b -n 1 -d1 |grep "Cpu(s)"| awk -F' ' '{print $2}'|awk -F' ' '{print $1}'
top: -d disallowed in "secure" mode
```

Comment: Check your `/etc/toprc` for `s` option and remove that.

Comment: let me check it and revert you back